# Show inbox notification banner when app is running

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, ios-app

If I'm viewing a question/answer in the app, and get an inbox message, there is zero notification of that until I close the app or return to a page that shows the inbox icon.

Is it possible to display the notification banner when receiving an inbox message and the inbox isn't visible? This is how for example Messages works when receiving a text from one contact while talking to another.

If that's not technically possible (Apple keeps the best APIs for themselves, don't they?) maybe in the least play the sound and vibrate.

Comment: The banner only shows up for backgrounded apps; notification center is skipped for foreground apps.  We could play a sound or have some other sort of visual feedback.  If you're on a screen with the notification icon, you would definitely see it update, but that's not every screen.

Comment: Well it definitely works in Apple's built-in apps like Mail and Messages, but it doesn't surprise me they don't expose it for third-party apps. Sound would be a good start though, thanks!